# sklearn decision tree using exactly same criterion multiple times

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have started learning scikit-learn using [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/decision-tree-classification-python) but getting this [decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDluW.jpg)

Shouldn't all Start_flow ≤ 0.611 values be separated at the start? There is no duplicate attribute in the dataset.

Comment: Strange indeed. Hard to say more without data. May be you have may values between 0.6105 and 0.6115. And those are different criterion, but that display similarly. Eg, the first one is `Start_flow<0.61149`, with 25288 samples for which it is true. And the second one is, `Start_flow<0.61051`. Meaning that among the 12374 samples for which `MiniLenrx > -0.286` and `Start_flow<0.61149`, 7265 have `Stat_flow<0.61051` and 5109 have `0.61051<=start_flow<0.61149`

Comment: Just of of curiosity, how many samples in your whole dataset have `0.6105 <= start_flow < 0.6115`? If that number is high that might be the explanation. If it is just a few, then we have to search for another reason

Comment: @chrslg Yes, there's a lot of data between 0.6105 and 0.6115. Loss of precision during tree visualization indeed. Thanks!